# In Shell, How to move the contents of a dir to another dir in same level

Tags: linux, shell

```
/tmp/test$ ls
dir1  dir2  dirM
/tmp/test$ mv * dirM/
mv: cannot move `dirM' to a subdirectory of itself, `dirM/dirM'
```

Is there a way to move everything (except dirM) to dirM using shell script?

Comment: Doesn't this work? dir1 and dir2 should be in dirM. You are only looking to get rid of the error message?

Comment: Your command does exactly that. It complains for trying to move the directory to itself as well, but aside from that, it does the job well.

Comment: `/tmp/test$ mv dir[12] dirM/` By using `'*'` you are trying to `mv dirM dirM` prompting the error...

Comment: yes, it does the work, I am trying to avoid the error.

Comment: avoid or hide? If you say `mv .... 2>/dev/null` you won't see it.

Comment: @fedorqui If he is in a script with -e set, redirecting standard error will still produce an error code and stop the script.

Comment: not to hide the error, but to find the right solution, thanks for all the replies.

Answer (score 2):

You don't say what shell you are using. In POSIX-compliant `sh`, you can loop over the contents of the directory, skipping `dirM`:

```
for d in ./*/; do
    [ ! -d "$d" ] || [ "$d" -eq "./dirM/" ] && continue
    mv "$d" dirM
done
```

In `bash`, you can use extended patterns to match all but `dirM`:

```
shopt -s extglob nullglob
for d in !(dirM)/; do
    mv "$d" dirM
done
```

In either case, if you simply want to hide the error, use

```
mv * dirM 2> /dev/null
```

This isn't recommended, as it will discard any error that might occur.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done like this

```
find  -type d  -not -name 'dirM' -exec mv {} 'dirM' \;
```

`-type d  -not -name 'dirM'`  #find all directories except dirM

`exec mv {} 'dirM'` #move these directories to dirM

Comment: You also need to remove . from the list. -not name '.'

Comment: A made a mistake, when I tried to undo it, it would not let me. I wanted it on my own post.

Answer (score 0):

Since my old answer was voted down, here is another. Much better than all the others.

```
mv !(dirM) DirM
```

Doesn't parse ls.
Tested under version 4.1-1

```
          !(pattern-list)
                 Matches anything except one of the given patterns
```

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching

Comment: Tested in bash version 4.1-1

Comment: Only works if `extglob` is enabled (`shopt -s extglob`) -- and by default it's turned off. I'm guessing you enable it in your dotfiles, but @Krish doesn't.

Answer (score -2):

How about:

```
mv $(ls -d * | grep -v ^dirM$) dirM
```

or if you are not using bash

```
mv `ls -d * | grep -v ^dirM$` dirM
```